# How to get a tag value from an XML in string

Tags: xml, shell, awk, sed

I have the below variable declared

```
TEXT='<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://ws.chpconsulting.com/alfa/requestcontext/v1" xmlns:v11="http://ws.chpconsulting.com/alfa/user/v1"><soapenv:Header><v1:context></v1:context></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><v11:load><!--Optional:--><userId>IN2Z83</userId></v11:load></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>'
```

How to get the userID tag value in the shell script

Comment: Use an XML parser and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 grep -o 'userId>.*</userId' | sed 's/^.*>//g;s/<.*$//g'
```

Demo:

```
$echo $TEXT
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://ws.chpconsulting.com/alfa/requestcontext/v1" xmlns:v11="http://ws.chpconsulting.com/alfa/user/v1"><soapenv:Header><v1:context></v1:context></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><v11:load><!--Optional:--><userId>IN2Z83</userId></v11:load></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
$echo $TEXT | grep -o 'userId>.*</userId' | sed 's/^.*>//g;s/<.*$//g'
IN2Z83
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a shell like `bash` that understands [here string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Here_strings) syntax, you can use a command-line XML tool like `xmlstarlet`:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//userId' <<< "$TEXT"
```

or `hxselect` from W3C's HTML-XML-Utils package:

```
hxselect -c userId <<< "$TEXT"
```

or another tool of your choice.

Otherwise, you can pipe the XML text to the tool:

```
echo "$TEXT" | xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//userId'
```